# Postgrey not greylisting incoming emails

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ubuntu-12.04, greylisting

I migrated my server to a new provider and have postfix & everything else back up and running, but am not getting incoming mails greylisted anymore when I have postgrey running. I was on CentOS 5.7 previously and now on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

postgrey is running

```
$ ps ax |grep postgrey
 1330 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto postgrey
32664 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/postgrey --pidfile=/var/run/postgrey.pid --daemonize --inet=10023 --delay=60
```

And is listening on port 10023

```
$ netstat -nlpa | grep postgrey
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32664/postgrey.pid
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    331119   32664/postgrey.pid
```

And here is the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` portion of my postfix main.cf, where i'm telling postfix to check postgrey via `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023`

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,

        permit_dnswl_client list.dnswl.org,

        reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_sender fresh15.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_client fresh15.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_sender uribl.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_client uribl.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_sender urired.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_client urired.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rhsbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2,

        reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.tiopan.com,
        reject_rbl_client spamsources.fabel.dk,
        reject_rbl_client truncate.gbudb.net,
        reject_rbl_client ubl.unsubscore.com,
        reject_rbl_client aspews.ext.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client backscatter.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spameatingmonkey.net,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.webequipped.com,
        reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,

        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
        permit
```

There shouldn't be anything else to the set up, right? I am not seeing anything getting NOQUEUE greylisted in my /var/log/mail.log, like i did with my previous setup on CentOS.

Is there a way for me to enable more verbose logging to see if postfix is communicating properly with postgrey and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question, as I figured out the issue...I was expecting test emails I was sending from gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc. to be initially greylisted on this new machine, but they weren't because I am using the `list.dnswl.org` whitelist (via `permit_dnswl_client list.dnswl.org`), and those IPs likely appear on that whitelist.

I went back to check on the logs again after some time and am seeing emails whitelisted properly.